# Changing a PHP script to PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

EDIT: Thank you for your answers.

I'm currently trying to change an old video display script to pdo, But pdo is a new concept to me and i need a little help.

Any help would be appreciated.
I thought i had the right idea, But apparently not.

```
     <?php
$dsn = 'dsn';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

$db = New PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$sq = db->query("SELECT * FROM  videos ORDER BY `VidTitle` ASC")

$i=0
while ($i < $sq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 
{
$FormattedComment = wordwrap($row->VidDesc;, 25, "\n", true);
?>


<div class="videobox1">
  <table height="230px" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="border:none;background:none;"><div class="LargeFont"><?php echo $row->VidTitle; ?></div>
  </td> 
  <td style="border:none;background:none;" align="center" valign="bottom" width="125px" colspan="2"><img style="border:none;background:none;" 
     src="../GuideResources/Words/pt.png" /><?php echo $row->VidTime; ?></td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td valign="bottom" style="border:none;background:none;"><img style="border:none;background:none;" src="../GuideResources/Words/expect.png"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="left" width="725" valign="top" ><div class="SmallFont">&nbsp;<?php echo $FormattedComment; ?></div></td>
  <td width="25px" style="border:none;background:none;">&nbsp;</td>
  <td style="border:none;background:none;" align="right"><div class="WatchNow"><a href="../Video/DisplayVideo.php?Video=<?php echo $row->ID; ?>&TrackUser=Videos">            </a></div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

When i run this i get the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /var/www/httpdocs/test.php on line 8
```

with the following changes i got this working just fine:

```
$db = New PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$sq = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Videos ORDER BY VidTitle ASC");


while ($row = $sq->fetchobject()) 
{
$FormattedComment = wordwrap($row->VidDesc, 25, "\n", true);
?>
```

Thank you to the few users who helped correct my simple mistakes,
and for my brain figuring out the other alteratation.

I think i'm beginning to under PDO a bit better, I just need to slow down.

Comment: This code is far from an example given in the tag wiki. Please use code from there.

Comment: Now your just being a douche.

Comment: @SamuelChristison He means here - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info and is mainly referring to how you're fetching / looping over the data

Comment: To his credit, its not readily clear that the "learn more…" link is also known as the "tag wiki" unless you hover over it. That said, those (for any tag) are great sources of information that SHOULD be read before posting if you are venturing in a "new" subject.

Comment: @Phil why is the method i'm using a bad one ?

Comment: @Uberfuzzy to his *credit*, he was given **direct link** in his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215702/coverting-an-old-php-script-to-php-pdo)

Comment: @SamuelChristison because it won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not related to PDO. It's a PHP syntax error:

You missed a trailing `;` on line 8 and 10

```
$sq = db->query("SELECT * FROM  videos ORDER BY `VidTitle` ASC")
```

Comment: Thank you. In my frustration i missed this.

Comment: Do people think their unhelpful posts to my apparently useless question are any more valid then mine ? I don't know, i wonder sometimes.

Comment: Someone vote this man up, i don't have the rep to do so, Hes the only helpful/non-sinical post i've had since joining today.

Comment: and missing the leading $ before the db on that same line. Any Parse/Syntax errors should be resolved before even thinking about logic like PDO. PHP has a built in syntax checker by using the "-l" parameter

Comment: Lol, I noticed that when i was correcting the first mistake -.-'

Thank you. 

I should spend less time raging, more time thinking haha.

Comment: @SamuelChristison One accepts an answer by clicking the outlined checkmark next to that answer.

Comment: @Daedalus Thank you kind sir for pointing this out to me.